# Como extrair apenas o penúltimo caractere de uma sequencia e depois usar o autopreenchimento no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma sequencia numérica separado por espaços, quero apenas extrair os números em vermelho, porém ao usar o autopreenchimento(clicar e arrastar para baixo com o cursor) não funciona! como eu faço para extrair apenas os números em vermelho de todas as células? e usar o autopreenchimento sem problemas, ?? 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solução

Para obter o penúltimo item da célula, utiliza a seguinte função na primeira célula e depois o autopreenchimento.

#### Fórmula

`=ARRUMAR(ESQUERDA(DIREITA(SUBSTITUIR(""&ARRUMAR(A1);" ";REPT(" ";40));80);40))`

Em que `" "` é o separador, que no caso é um espaço. Esta fórmula funciona somente com espaço como separador.

### Separador diferente de espaço

Caso o separador seja diferente de espaço, por exemplo um hífen `-`

Como na tabela a seguir:

```
+---+----------------------------+---------+
|   |             A              |    B    |
+---+----------------------------+---------+
| 1 | 1-22-333-4444-55555-666666 | 55555   |
| 2 | 1-22-333-4444-55555        | 4444    |
| 3 | 1-22-333-4444              | 333     |
| 4 | 1-22-333                   | 22      |
| 5 | 1-22                       | 1       |
| 6 | 1                          | 1       |
+---+----------------------------+---------+
```

Uma função personalizada (UDF) pode ser criada no VBA:

```
Function EXTRAIRPENULTIMO(Txt As String, Separador As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    contador = Len(Txt) - Len(Replace(Txt, Separador, ""))
    If contador = 0 Then
        EXTRAIRPENULTIMO = Txt
    Else
        EXTRAIRPENULTIMO = Split(Application.Trim(Mid(Txt, 1)), Separador)(contador - 1)
    End If
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ' error handling code
    EXTRAIRPENULTIMO = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

E na coluna `B` a seguinte fórmula é usada:

`=EXTRAIRPENULTIMO(B1;"-")`

Comment: Muito bom. Mas seria possível inserir uma outra sequencia de numeração na frente do penúltimo, por exemplo uma numeração que esta antes do "55555" ou depois? no caso ficaria: B1: 55555 4444, ou se tivesse a sequencia "7" na frente da sequencia "666666",  B1: 55555 7777777, ??

Comment: seria o valor antes e o depois do penúltimo? Portanto, uma concatenação do último e antepenúltimo? Sugiro realizar outra pergunta

Comment: Sim. Eu vou fazer outra pergunta

Answer (score 1):

A fórmula ficou meio grande

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso específico do penúltimo valor entre espaços fica

```
=SE(
  NÚM.CARACT(A1) - NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A1; " ";""))<1;
  "";
  SE(
    NÚM.CARACT(A1) - NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A1; " ";""))=1;
    ESQUERDA(A1;LOCALIZAR(" ";A1));
    EXT.TEXTO(
      A1;
      LOCALIZAR("|";SUBSTITUIR(A1;" ";"|";NÚM.CARACT(A1)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A1;" ";""))-1))+1;
      LOCALIZAR("|";SUBSTITUIR(A1;" ";"|";NÚM.CARACT(A1)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A1;" ";"")))) -
      LOCALIZAR("|";SUBSTITUIR(A1;" ";"|";NÚM.CARACT(A1)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A1;" ";""))-1))-1
    )
  )
)
```

E uma generalização disso seria

```
=SE(
  NÚM.CARACT($A1) - NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR($A1; " ";""))<C$7;
  "";
  SE(
    NÚM.CARACT($A1) - NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR($A1; " ";""))=C$7;
    ESQUERDA($A1;LOCALIZAR(" ";$A1));
    EXT.TEXTO(
      $A1;
      LOCALIZAR("|";SUBSTITUIR($A1;" ";"|";NÚM.CARACT($A1)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR($A1;" ";""))-C$7))+1;
      LOCALIZAR("|";SUBSTITUIR($A1;" ";"|";NÚM.CARACT($A1)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR($A1;" ";""))-C$7+1)) -
      LOCALIZAR("|";SUBSTITUIR($A1;" ";"|";NÚM.CARACT($A1)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR($A1;" ";""))-C$7))-1
    )
  )
)
```